Num lock keeps coming on, won't stay off
I decided to install ubuntu on a 2015 Lenovo Yoga.  My main goal is to learn Linux by using Linux -- I use Windows, ChromeOS, Home Assistant, python.  A couple of the Yoga keys have to be mashed incredibly hard to fire (though then they work for a while), so I got an external, USB keyboard.  Num lock keeps coming on after being turned off.
I've installed numlockx and run terminal commands to disable num lock.  It does not stay disabled.  Usually a backspace will turn it back on when off.  Another symptom is that often the num lock key won't turn off unless I depress it for 3 seconds.
The Yoga does not seem to have controls for num lock in bios.
Is there a way of turning num lock off permanently?
Most of the discussion online concerns getting num lock to stay on.  I have tried doing the opposite (e.g. replacing 'on' with 'off', true with false) without success.  Much of what I found online concerns earlier versions of Ubuntu with different controls from the current version.
I'm on 24.04.1 LTS

Just to rule out that the possibility that the keyboard is the problem, I connected the keyboard to a chromeOS laptop and a windows laptop, and numlock did not come on automatically on either device, so it does not appear to be a problem with the keyboard itself.
